# Advanced mathematical expressions in JavaScript - How to

Tags: javascript, math, mathematical-expressions

I am about to do some calculating with JavaScript. How do one write (rather complex) *mathematical* expressions in JavaScript?

Let's take this as an example, where I use x as a variable:

-2(10^ -10)x^6

Is it possible to write it just like that? Or should I write something like this:

`-2 * math.pow(10, -10) * math.pow(x, 6)` ?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are interested in using that notation for readability look at:
http://mathjs.org/

which allows for an eval call on this type of notation.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is correct. (but require capital m eg `Math`)

In JavaScript `^` is XOR and `*` is required for multiplication.

Comment: Tried it that way again, but it did nor work. I found the problem though! A upper case "M" is required! So "Math.pow(10, -10)", not "math.pow(10, -10)"

Comment: Easy to miss little mistakes like those when you assume something is correct. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

> -2(10^ -10)x^6

The above statement will never work. It will give you an `unexpected identifier` because of `)x` and `2 is not a function` because of `-2(`..

> -2 * math.pow(10, -10) * math.pow(x, 6)

This will also won't work as its `Math` and not `math` as Javascript is case-sensitive.

Proper way is

```
-2 * Math.pow(10, -10) * Math.pow(x, 6)
```